# Remote access to SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to allow remote access to my SQL Server.  The purpose is to check user status, which is located on a database in my SQL Server.  When accessing the Server is attempted, an error message is received saying the server is not accessible.  I have enabled remote access, and have allowed for access in the windows firewall.  Yet the error message persists.  I am thinking maybe I am not writing the path correctly in my C# code.  Any input on what the problem might be is much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you already able to access your db server in another way than through your c# code?

Comment: First try to access your SQL server through i.e Excel. Open Data->Get data->From Database.... It may be that your TCP/IP protocol is not configured correctly

Comment: On your question on can I access the db server through my code, yes when I run tests on my computer.  When I send the software to another computer, that is when the code no longer works and I get the cannot access the database.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of dabase are you using? Are you checking for information through your C# code or do you wish to see the database information directly in the database?

If it is the last option, i recommend you to take a look at Webmin. It is an open source Web GUI for linux. You can install a database server through there, along with apache server and a bunch of other stuff. You can find more information about it on [their website](https://www.webmin.com/).

Comment: The software itself utilizes a locally installed SQLite database.  However, upon launch, the code reaches out to my SQL Server database, to check if version number payment status is current.  That is where the problem lies, when accessing the SQL Server database, a message says it cannot be accessed.  This is the code I am using that is returning the cannot access :

Comment: SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HQBALSGK\\MSSQLSERVER05;Initial Catalog=TestConnection;Integrated Security=True");
sqlcon.Open();

SqlCommand xgatecmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Paid FROM VersionTbl WHERE VersionNumber = @VersionNumber", sqlcon);
xgatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VersionNumber", gateKeeperNumber);
string gateKeeper = Convert.ToString(xgatecmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, because the content is not a clear answer to the question

Comment: My bad @EduardKeilholz. I have been using Stackoverflow for years, but only recently registered and started using it properly. Thanks for pointing that out, i see now how i can comment properly.